# How can I add CDN in php using require_once()?

Tags: php

I'm trying to insert my CSS which is in github repo but when I call it in my php file using
**require_once()** it's not working.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
require_once("https://nishant5harma.github.io/Ctools/Ctools__CSS/navbar.css");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello</p>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone help me out with this that is it possible? to do this someting like this or I have to store my file in my local system to do this?

**After trying some solution still getting this blank page?**
[image]

Comment: Is it getting an error?

Comment: @Barmar no it's not showing anything

Comment: Is your error reporting on? You might be getting something like `require 'https://nishant5harma.github.io/Ctools/Ctools__CSS/navbar.css';
Warning: require(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in php`. However, this works fine regardless: `$f = file_get_contents('https://nishant5harma.github.io/Ctools/Ctools__CSS/navbar.css');
echo $f;`.

Comment: It's obviously not being output where it should ie. inside `<head>` tags, and further inside `<style>` tags. Assuming fetching the CSS from an URL works to begin with. Which you should test, as above.  Github isn't exactly a CDN though. Aside that, you do realize though that your _script will be waiting while it's being fetched_, which is pretty much the opposite effect of what you want from using a CDN. Why don't you just link to the CSS the usual way, with `<link ...>`, and let the browser handle the loading?

Comment: @MarkusAO but it give me file content but I want to use it as CDN

Answer (score 1):

The CSS needs to be inside a `<style>` tag, which should be in `<head>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    <?php
    require_once("https://nishant5harma.github.io/Ctools/Ctools__CSS/navbar.css");
    ?>
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<p>Hello</p>
    
</body>
</html>
```

You also need to enable URLs in `include/require` with

```
allow_url_include = On
```

in your `php.ini`.

Although normally you would have the client do this using a `<link>` tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://nishant5harma.github.io/Ctools/Ctools__CSS/navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello</p>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hum, wouldn't PHP get a syntax error by requiring non-PHP code ?

Comment: @Barmar but I have tried this it's not working in php

Comment: @AymDev No. Remember, PHP will process fixed text until it gets to `<?php`.

Comment: @joker Do you have `allow_url_include=1` in your php.ini?

Comment: @joker "it's not working" doesn't mean anything to us. You need to tell _how you notice that it's not working, ie. what happens instead of the expected result_.

Comment: @joker I enabled `allow_url_include` and it worked for me.

Comment: @Barmar I tried this but still my background color is not getting red?

Comment: If you do View Source, do you see the CSS in the `<style>` block?

Comment: @Barmar yes I am able to see <style> block.

Comment: @Barmar I create php.ini folder too and write ```allow_url_include = On``` this

Comment: Then it's not a PHP problem. Something else is overriding your styles.